# visual studio c# code file inherit problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Building a web project with C#. Have a `login.aspx` page with the general login values, textboxes, buttons etc.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="account_login" %>
```

On my code behind file `login.aspx.cs` I am trying to check the value of the `emailTxt` textbox from the `login.aspx` page. However I am getting the error:

> CS0436:
>   The type 'account_login' in 'I:\CSC3052\accountpages\login.aspx' conflicts with the imported type 'account_login' in 'CIT7, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 'I:\CSC3052\accountpages\login.aspx'.

Can anyone advise what to do? If more detail is needed just ask.

Comment: Do you have any class name account_login ?

Comment: See I think that's the problem. The webpage is login.aspx, I don't know where it's pulling the word 'account' from but even if I change 'account_login' to just 'login' I still get the same error.

Comment: Then, when trying to reference the textbox from the cs code behind file I get:

CS0103 The name 'emailTxt' does not exist in the current context CIT7 I:\CSC3052\accountpages\login.aspx.cs

Comment: The file name might not be the class name. Have a look at the actual class name. Search for that string in your whole solution might be a good start

Comment: account_login is the name of the class (in the code behind file), as you can see, the aspx page is trying to inherit from the class account_login. `Inherits="account_login"`. What is the class name in login.aspx.cs?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class account_login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    protected void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string uName = emailTxt.Text;
        //string pWord = passwordTxt.Text;
        
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

refer [CS0436: Type conflicts with the imported type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962066/cs0436-type-conflicts-with-the-imported-type).

The only time conflicts occur is when two dependent classes include the same class. There are three workarounds:

1.Disable the warning in classes that cause CS0436:
**pragma warning disable 0436**

2.Have a separate instance of the class, uniquely named in each client project (undesirable from a maintenance point of view).

3. if classes are internally to the assembly. Make the license class internal and this should fix the problem. Much better than a pragma.