# The type [some view] conflicts with the imported type [default view] (CS0436)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to override a razor view found in a nuget package that I am using. The view is defined in an MVC Area.

When building, I get a warning/error that the views conflict. Lucky for me, it seems my custom view that overrides the package view is used and when using the view it loads as I hoped it would, but I really would like to get rid of the warning and override the view in a correct way.

**The error**

> error CS0436:
>
> The type [Areas_AreaName_Views_SomeFolder_Login] in
>
> [.../obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Areas/AreaName_Views_SomeFolder_Login]
>
> conflicts with the imported type
>
> [Areas_AreaName_Views_SomeFolder_Login] in
>
> [The Nuget Package Namespace].
>
> Using the type defined in [.../obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Areas/AreaName_Views_SomeFolder_Login].

This question has the same error but for classes:

[CS0436: Type conflicts with the imported type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962066/cs0436-type-conflicts-with-the-imported-type)

This project simply hides the error:

https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/pull/3720

How can I override an area view defined in a package properly?

What does the package need to provide and what do I as the user of the package need to do?

Perhaps it is possible to exclude the view from the nuget package somehow?

Comment: Facing the same problem, any updates on that?

Comment: @DominikAmon I simply ignored the error and it is still working. Would love a proper solution/explanation though.